# Parafrasare 'chiederle' in 'Quali authority, se posso chiederle?' in modo che non sembri 'chiedere a Lei'

Tags: grammar

Come si parafrasa 'chiederle' in

> Quali authority, se posso chiederle?

in modo che non sembri

> Quali authority, se posso chiederLe?

?

Ciò per evitare che quel 'le'—che è riferito alle authority—sembri 'a Lei' in una conversazione dove due persone si danno del Lei.

Comment: *Se posso chiedere*

Comment: Buffamente è esattamente come in tedesco: _wenn ich sie fragen darf_ vs. _wenn ich Sie fragen darf_, e la soluzione è la stessa: _wenn ich fragen darf_.

Comment: Confesso che a me suona un po' strana la domanda nel senso in cui “chiederle” = “chiedere le authority” (non diresti “chiedere le authority”, no? diresti “chiedere quali sono le a.”, “chiedere i nomi della a.” etc.).

Comment: D'accordo con egreg, o anche “se posso chiederlo/se lo posso chiedere”.

Answer (score 2):

La domanda *Quali xyz, se posso chiederle?* ha, indipendentemente dal genere di *xyz* un solo significato: quello in cui si sta dando del lei all'interlocutore
(anche se forse nel parlato può scappare con il pronome riferito a *xyz*).

> *Quali collane/vigne/montagne/autocarri, se posso chiederle?*

Il pronome non sottindende l'aggettivo “quale” e *se posso chiedere le vigne* non sembra corretto.

Più conforme all'uso mi pare una delle tre seguenti

> *Quali vigne, se posso chiedere?*
>   *Quali vigne, se posso chiederlo?*
>   *Quali vigne, se lo posso chiedere?*

Il pronome (al maschile, ma in realtà di genere indefinito) si riferisce alla domanda stessa, cioè *quali vigne?*